# Whats the best way to split an array in ruby into multiple smaller arrays of random size

Tags: ruby, arrays, random, slice

I have multiple arrays in ruby of variable length from 1 to 40 :

@items is a typical array which could be anywhere from 1 to 40 in length. eg

```
@items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

I want to randomly split the array into smaller arrays of lengths either 1, 2 or 3 to give a result of (for example)

```
@items = [[1, 2],[3],[4,5,6]]
```

or

```
@items = [[1],[2, 3],[4],[5,6]]
```

etc

I know you can split the array using @items.each_slice(3)... where 3 is a fixed length. But i want to randomly split large arrays of variable length into array sizes of 1,2 or 3 randomly... Whats the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 7):

```
items, @items = @items.dup, []
@items.push(items.shift(rand(1..3))) until items.empty?
```

Comment: Nice. If one's ruby is older than 1.9.3 [`Kernel#rand`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Kernel.html#method-i-rand) only takes an fixnum max, not a range. `@items.push(items.shift(1+rand(3))) until items.empty?` works for older rubies.

Answer (score 3):

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
b = []
until a.empty?
  b << a.shift((1..a.size).to_a.sample)
end
# b => [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9], [10]]
# change everytime though
```

You can limit the sub arrays size by replacing the `a.size` with `3` or anything you want.

Answer (score 1):

Just for yucks, I thought I'd try a pure functional form with no mutating methods for this problem:

```
( (0..@items.size)
    .inject([0]) { |m,_| m + [m.last + 1 + rand(3)] }
    .take_while  { |i| i < @items.size } + [@items.size] ).
  each_cons(2).
  map { |s,e| @items[s...e] }
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution maybe uses too many local variables, but it is non-destructive to the input array and flexible on array window maximum.

```
def rotateAndTake inputArray, windowSize
  rotator, returnArray, breaker = 0, [], true
  while breaker do
    window = rand(windowSize)+1
    if(rotator + window > inputArray.length) then
      window = inputArray.length - rotator
      breaker = false
    end
    returnArray << inputArray.rotate(rotator).take(window) if window > 0
    rotator += window
  end
  returnArray
end
```

Also, I just wanted to write a solution that used the "rotate" method.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another functional solution:

```
( [0]+
  (1..a.length-1)
    .to_a
    .sample(rand(a.length))
    .sort+
  [a.length]
).each_cons(2).map{|i,j| a[i..j-1]}
```

Comment: this can produce subarrays of length > 3.  `a[i...j]` is a nicer way to say `a[i..j-1]`.  I believe it may be biased to shorter subarrays.